# Maintaining sessions in jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have login form using jQuery mobile with PHP back end MySQL. Now, how do I maintain the session for the individual user in that.
Thanks,
Raj.

Comment: let's see.... http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Answer (score 0):

I would check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/964071/correct-way-to-manage-sessions-in-php/18837094#18837094) in order to set the sessions for PHP. Basically, you send username and pasword to the server, then get a session id, and store it in a cookie (see [this post about sessions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2257631/how-create-a-session-using-javascript) in javascript).

Regards,
Moreno.