# What is the correct way to store a value that was sent from browser into $_SESSION?

Tags: php, html, session, isset

So I want to retrieve the data stored in a `<input type='text'>` tag, and then store it in the `$_SESSION` array on my server.

I'm using a method of sending a GET request with ajax, then assign the value from `$_GET` to `$_SESSION`, so I can use the session value later.

The AJAX get request:

```
var xhttp = window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
console.log('Sending email address to system')
xhttp.open('GET','database.php?email='+email_address, false)
xhttp.send()
```

And then in `database.php`:

```
 if(isset($_GET['email'])){
    $_SESSION['email'] = $_GET['email'];
  }
```

Is there an easier way to do this? Some kind of http request that just stores that data into `$_SESSION` directly instead of using `$_GET?` in the middle?

Comment: Short answer is No, in fact you are not doing enough, you need to at least sanitize the input and you may consider validating the email and returning an error/success message.

Answer (score 0):

You might:

- start session
- do your session saving/updating/chanings
- destroy session if necessary or you can set/unset variables

---

#### Example

```
// Maybe, start of index.php
session_start();

if(isset($_GET['email'])){
    $_SESSION['email'] = $_GET['email'];
}


// after everything is over, you may want to destroy it: 
session_destroy();
```

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/964071/correct-way-to-manage-sessions-in-php) also has some additional info.